# How to get a feedback that something connected to an Arduino is working?

Tags: arduino-uno

Assume you have an Arduino Uno board, the board is connected to some sensors, maybe a stepper motor or something, it does not matter.

How to get feedback or diagnostics or something that all the things are working, or if not then get feedback that are not working?

Comment: It all depends on what the devices are and how they work. As an example, you could add current shunts to the motor connections and sense the current flowing through the motor.

Comment: with sensors you can check if the values are in expected range

Comment: moving parts can be checked with optical or electromagnetic sensors

Comment: there is nothing special for Arduino. it is common design of a system

Comment: OP asked how to provide feedback that there is or isn't a problem, not how to diagnose one. That's pretty straightforward, and I'd be happy to offer an answer if this were re-opened. Voting to do so....

Comment: Thank you all for the comments , have a ncie day , i think i got it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general mean of error detection in microcontrollers, so also not for an Arduino. Problems can occur at many points, extremely depending on how your project works. Think about a sensor, that is connected over some network bus; the sensor itself may fail, but also the network bus, so that you are not able to connect to the sensor anymore. Also the Arduino has no possibility to report errors to you, that you didn't anticipated in your sketch (like the log files on a PC would do). So there is not one answer for it. Here are some possibilities (some of them already described in previous answers):

- Check the output of library functions for error messages. Many (but not all) libraries return status codes from their important functions. For example: The `Wire.endTransmission()` function will return a status code, with which you can determine, if the transmission succeded and what might have gone wrong.
- Check sensors for expected values. If the values go out of range (for example a temperature of -20°C where you would expect room temperature) you can be pretty sure, that something is wrong with the sensor (assuming it worked properly before).
- Add sensors to your project, to sense, if it is working as expected, and program the Arduino to do the corresponding actions on failure (for example an alarm)

The first two options are simple, the third can get very complex and expensive and is normally only used, if the project really demands sensing malfunction electronically (like for a robot, that could hurt humans, when moving in the wrong direction).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Juraj's answers, tackle this question from the user's point of view. What does *all things are working* mean for them? Does the temperature you read from a sensor have to be within .2C of a reference value? The stepper has to move a thing from defined positions A to B?

Based on the answers to questions like this, which is sort of a [black-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) approach, think about how to obtain reference values, then write tests in your Arduino to check if they are met. You might have to move your system into a defined testing stage first, like move the steppers to a defined starting point, then go test.